# Unresolved Inclusion libxml++ Eclipse Mars CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, libxml2

I installed Eclipse Mars CDT and libxml++-3.0.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and I am having issues with an 'Unresolved Inclusion' error for the #include  in my C++ code.

I added libxml++ to the path as well by going to the project properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->GNU C++ 'Add...'. I did the same for libxml2 as well since libxml++ is dependent on libxml2.

However, I am still having this 'Unresolved Inclusion' error, so I am unable to build my project. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong here? I can not seem to figure it out yet.

Comment: I was able to resolve the 'Unresolved Inclusion' error but there are still errors that exist related to the inclusion of libxml++. Many of them are 'Method <> could not be resolved' or 'Invalid arguments' errors for functions such as add_child, set_attribute, add_child_text, get_attribute, etc. I will try to solve these errors and answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the 3.0.0 version of libxml++ is not a stable version. I downloaded 2.6.1 and it seems to be running fine.